# Using boost::bind but allowing any additional parameters to be passed through

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++03, boost-bind

I am putting together a "simple" template class. It offers an interface for performing some operations on a database, so there are other members as well (primarily for operating on the container member). However, for our purposes, the template class looks something like this:

```
template<typename T, //the type of objects the class will be manipulating
         typename S> //the signature of the function the class will be using
FunctionHandler
{
private:
    std::vector<T> container;
    boost::function<S> the_operation;
    SomeClass* pSC; //a database connection; implementation unimportant

    //some other members--not relevant here
public:
    boost::function<???> Operate;
    FunctionHandler(boost::function<S> the_operation_)
        : the_operation(the_operation_)
    {
        Operate = boost::bind(the_operation, pSC, std::back_inserter<std::vector<T> >,
                              /*infer that all other parameters passed to Operate
                                should be passed through to the_operation*/);
    }

    //other peripheral functions
}
```

My question is two-fold.

1. What do I put as the template parameter for `Operate`. i.e. what replaces `???`
2. How do I tell `boost::bind` that it should pass any other parameters given to `Operate` on to `the_operation`? In other words, for some arbitrary function signature `S` that looks like `void (SomeClass*, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<T> >, int, bool)` and some other arbitrary function signature `O` that looks like `void (SomeClass*, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<T> >, double, double, bool)` how do I write this template class such that `Operate` has a signature of `void (int, bool)` for the first and `void (double, double, bool)` for the second, and passes its values on to `the_operation`'s 3rd-Nth parameters?

In my searches I couldn't find any questions quite like this one.

Comment: How should the compiler check that the argument types are compatible with the function parameter types? How shall it insert conversions from the argument types to the function parameter types?

Comment: I don't know. Answering that is part of answering the question, isn't it? The intended use would be that at both compiletime and runtime the argument types match the parameter types.

Comment: As far as I know, it's impossible for arbitrary sets of types. The moment you store something in a `boost::function`, you erase all information about it (for the outside) and replace it with a single interface (return value + parameter types). `boost::function` seems not to support the ellipsis either. You could work around that issue by adding something like a `void*` to the function signature of `boost::function`, and then passing the additional parameters via this pointer. But still, this does not include neither type checks nor conversions.

Comment: In that case, what I desire is not obtainable via `boost::function` directly. Are there other possible implementations I could try?

Comment: @caps Lemme make sure I understand correctly. You have `S` is some function that takes, say, 4 arguments... and you want to bind the first two, and have the result be a function that takes 2 arguments and calls `the_operation` with the 2 bound ones and the two passed ones?

Comment: @Barry That's right.

Comment: I might have misunderstood you. I thought you wanted a fixed signature `S` for `boost::function<S> Operate` such that you can store various functions in it that have different signatures (like `void(SomeClass*, some_type, int, bool)` and `void(SomeClass*, some_type, double, double, bool)`; and any additional arguments passed to `Operate` should be forwarded to the stored function.

Comment: @dyp That may or may not be necessary for the solution to the problem. From where I set I don't think `Operate` will require an invariant signature across all instantiations of `FunctionHandler`, unless there is a special invariant signature that would do what I want. I am not sure. That is (part of) why I asked the question. A possible solution might involve `Operate` having a variant signature deduced from `S`. EDIT: No. *Within a single instantiation of `FunctionHandler`*, `Operate`'s signature would be invariant.

Comment: Let me rephrase my doubts: Would it be sufficient to get the list of parameter types from `S` (the template parameter of `FunctionHandler`), then prepend the two types `SomeClass*, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<T> >` to that list, and form the signature `???` from this new list and the return type in `S`?

Comment: @dyp That sounds like a possible solution, yes. However, I believe that `SomeClass*` and `std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<T> >` will be absent from `???`, where they will be part of `S`. In other words, `FunctionHandler` will require `S` to have those two as its first two parameters, but they will not be parameters on `Operate`, which serves as the public interface for `member_function`. Let me know if that is not clear on re-reading the question--I may need to edit it.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. So you need to remove the first two parameter types from `S` to get `???`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why even use bind? We can get the same effect without it. I'm using `Iter` as a template but you can fill it in with whater the right type is:

```
template <typename S, typename Iter>
class Operator
{
    boost::function<S> func_;
    SomeClass* cls_;
    Iter iter_;

public:
    Operator(function<S> func, SomeClass* cls, Iter iter)
    : func_(func), cls_(cls), iter_(iter)
    { }

    // one for each # of args
    typename boost::result_of<
        boost::function<S>(SomeClass*, Iter)
    >::type operator()() const {
        return func_(cls_, iter_);
    }

    template <typename A>
    typename boost::result_of<
        boost::function<S>(SomeClass*, Iter, A)
    >::type operator()(A a) const {
        return func_(cls_, iter_, a);
    }

    template <typename A, typename B>
    typename boost::result_of<
        boost::function<S>(SomeClass*, Iter, A, B)
    >::type operator()(A a, B b) const {
        return func_(cls_, iter_, a, b);
    }

    // etc.
};
```

We're making all of the `operator()`s, but they'll only get instantiated if they get called - so as long as you call the right one (which for any solution, you'll have to anyway), this works.

Comment: Do I need to use `boost::result_of` here? Couldn't I have the return type as another parameter of the template?

Comment: @caps It'd be redundant. The return type is part of `S`.

Comment: Yes, but if I pass the return type on its own I don't need to use `boost::result_of`. "Using boost" is something my co-workers prefer to do as little as possible, for a variety of good and bad reasons. I'll probably float the `result_of` solution first, I just need to know if it is possible to get by without it.

Comment: @caps You're already using boost though. Can you use C++11? I can give you a non-boost C++11 solution :)

Comment: No, for our purposes C++11 is not really available from our IDE. We do use `boost`, but our approach is "use `boost` when you *need* it."

Comment: Two notes: 1) could you leave the other answer up for posterity? It might be more preferable for some users in the future, for reasons specific to their own use case. Although I like this answer better.  2) I am getting "error: declaration of 'operator()' as non-function" when I try to compile this on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba7957c28af6701f).

Comment: @caps (1) I like this one better, but sure. That one you actually have to do `using namespace boost;` which is even worse than just having to use it :) (2) Fixed! Really silly error on my part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67389/discussion-between-caps-and-barry).

Comment: To get rid of the repeated `boost::result_of` for each overload, you could use my technique to remove the first two parameters of `S`. Then, you need only one typedef: `typedef typename boost::function_types::result_type<typename without_first_2_parameters<S>::type>::type result_type;`

Comment: @dyp I tried that. coliru complained about the syntax you posted there and I didn't want to spend time trying to figure it out. Barry's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way to "infer" all the rest of the arguments. You have to specify all the correct placeholders. Since C++03, we can just use lots of template specializations.

```
template <typename S> struct Operate;

template <typename R, typename Iter>
struct Operate<R(SomeClass*, Iter)>
{
    using namespace boost;

    function<R()> op_;

    Operator(function<R(SomeClass*, Iter)> op, SomeClass* cls, Iter iter)
    : op_(bind(op, cls, iter))
    { }
};

template <typename R, typename Iter, typename A>
struct Operate<R(SomeClass*, Iter, A)>
{
    using namespace boost;

    function<R(A)> op_;

    Operator(function<R(SomeClass*, Iter, A)> op, SomeClass* cls, Iter iter)
    : op_(bind(op, cls, iter, _1))
    { }
};

template <typename R, typename Iter, typename A, typename B>
struct Operate<R(SomeClass*, Iter, A, B)>
{
    using namespace boost;

    function<R(A, B)> op_;

    Operator(function<R(SomeClass*, Iter, A, B)> op, SomeClass* cls, Iter iter)
    : op_(bind(op, cls, iter, _1, _2))
    { }
};

// etc.
```

It's verbose, but if you can't use C++11, I don't know what else you could do. Which, for completeness:

```
template <typename R, typename Iter, typename... Extra>
struct Operator<R(SomeClass*, Iter, Extra...)>
{
    std::function<R(SomeClass*, Iter, Extra...)> op_;
    SomeClass* cls_;
    Iter iter_;

    Operator(function<R(SomeClass*, Iter, Extra...)> op, SomeClass* cls, Iter iter)
    : op_(op), cls_(cls), iter_(iter)
    { }

    R operator()(Extra... args) const {
        return op_(cls_, iter_, args...);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

My knowledge of boost.MPL is unfortunately quite limited, so I don't think this is the nicest way to solve the issue of *removing the first two parameter types from a function type*.

```
#include <boost/function_types/components.hpp>
#include <boost/function_types/function_type.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/erase.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/begin_end.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/advance.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>

template<typename F, int N>
class remove_first_N_param_types
{
        typedef typename boost::function_types::components<F>::type
    components;
        typedef typename boost::mpl::begin<components>::type
    beg;
        typedef typename boost::mpl::advance<beg, boost::mpl::int_<1  >>::type
    beg_param;
        typedef typename boost::mpl::advance<beg, boost::mpl::int_<1+N>>::type
    beg_param_plus_N;
        typedef typename boost::mpl::erase<components,
                                           beg_param, beg_param_plus_N>::type
    erased_first_N_params;

public:
        typedef typename boost::function_types::
        function_type<erased_first_N_params>::type
    type;
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fc37aa4f1da67dd)

Comment: This gives you the type, but how would you construct it?

Comment: Yes, this lets you define `Operate` as `boost::function<remove_first_N_param_types<F, 2> > Operate` which, while cool, doesn't show how to construct `Operate` from `member_function`. I'll give this one an upvote though, since I suspect it could be useful to readers in the future.

Comment: @caps d'oh, I've done this for C++11 already, but I cannot find a decent way in C++03 to do it - only with techniques to mimic variadic templates (similar to Barry's first answer). It can be simplified a bit by using `boost::arg<N>` instead of the named placeholders, but the manual overloading or specialization remains, unless you use macros.